# Kotlin How to create dynamic Object

Tags: kotlin

In javascript we can do something like this

```js
function putritanjungsari(data){
 console.log(data.name)
}

let data = {
 name:"putri",
 div:"m4th"
}
putritanjungsari(data)
```

In kotlin, i'am creating a function that accept an object as parameter then read it's properties later, how to do that in kotlin that targeting JVM?

Comment: While this is possible (e.g. using a Map), you should be aware that it has many disadvantages: it's likely to be slower and take more memory than standard properties; you lose lots of compile-time checking, making several types of bug much more likely; users/callers of your code won't be able to tell what properties are available; inheritance is much harder, as is customising getters/setters, quality, and comparison…  Sometimes it's needed, but very rarely IME — if you're coming from a dynamic language, please ensure you're not just doing so because it's more familiar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question correct, you are trying to have a variable that associates keys with some value or undefined(null in kt) if none are found. You  are searching for a [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html)
If you don't know what types you want, you can make a map of type Any? So

```
Map<String, Any?>
```

Which is also nullable

```
Map<String, Any>
```

If you don't want nullables

Your code for example:

```
fun putritanjungsari(data: Map<String, Any?>){
print(data["name"]) 
}

val data: Map<String, Any?> =mapOf(        
"name" to "putri",
"div" to "m4th" 
)
putritanjungsari(data)
```

Note that you can't add new keys  or edit any data here, the default map is immutable. There is MutableMap (which is implemented the same, only it has a method to put new data)

Comment: yes, but since i want everything to be dynamic and we don't know what is its data type, i think it will be better if we use something dynamic class just like in JS

Comment: A any map would be better in that case

Comment: Or any? If you want nullables

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto I've made some edits, check my answer and also the one above as he might have figured out what you actually meant

Comment: can you give an example with my snippet?

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the [property design pattern](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/property/) to solve your problem.

Here is its implementation in Kotlin:

```
interface DynamicProperty<T> {
    fun cast(value: Any?): T
    fun default(): T

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T> fromDefaultSupplier(crossinline default: () -> T) =
            object : DynamicProperty<T> {
                override fun cast(value: Any?): T = value as T
                override fun default(): T = default()
            }

        inline operator fun <reified T> invoke(default: T) = fromDefaultSupplier { default }

        inline fun <reified T> required() = fromDefaultSupplier<T> {
            throw IllegalStateException("DynamicProperty isn't initialized")
        }

        inline fun <reified T> nullable() = DynamicProperty<T?>(null)
    }
}

operator fun <T> DynamicProperty<T>.invoke(value: T) = DynamicPropertyValue(this, value)

data class DynamicPropertyValue<T>(val property: DynamicProperty<T>, val value: T)

class DynamicObject(vararg properties: DynamicPropertyValue<*>) {
    private val properties = HashMap<DynamicProperty<*>, Any?>().apply {
        properties.forEach { put(it.property, it.value) }
    }

    operator fun <T> get(property: DynamicProperty<T>) =
        if (properties.containsKey(property)) property.cast(properties[property])
        else property.default()

    operator fun <T> set(property: DynamicProperty<T>, value: T) = properties.put(property, value)
    operator fun <T> DynamicProperty<T>.minus(value: T) = set(this, value)
}

fun dynamicObj(init: DynamicObject.() -> Unit) = DynamicObject().apply(init)
```

You can define your properties these ways:

```
val NAME = DynamicProperty.required<String>() // throws exceptions on usage before initialization
val DIV = DynamicProperty.nullable<String>() // has nullable type String?
val IS_ENABLED = DynamicProperty(true) // true by default
```

Now you can use them:

```
fun printObjName(obj: DynamicObject) {
    println(obj[NAME])
}

val data = dynamicObj {
    NAME - "putri"
    DIV - "m4th"
}
printObjName(data)

// throws exception because name isn't initialized
printObjName(DynamicObject(DIV("m4th"), IS_ENABLED(false)))
```

Reasons to use `DynamicObject` instead of `Map<String, Any?>`:

1. Type-safety (`NAME - 3` and `NAME(true)` will not compile)
2. No casting is required on properties usage
3. You can define what the program should do when a property isn't initialized

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is statically typed language, so it required a param type to be precisely defined or unambiguously inferred (Groovy, for instance, addresses the case by at least two ways). But for JS interoperability Kotlin offers [dynamic type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html).

Meanwhile, in your particular case you can type *data* structure to kt's Map and do not argue with strict typing.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [Any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/index.html) and after that, you have to cast your object, like this

```
private fun putritanjungsari(data : Any){
    if(data is Mydata){
        var data =  data as? Mydata
        data.name
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems closest approach, how to know where is data inherit from, or what kind of instance is data

Comment: you are calling this function using different object then you know that I am calling this function using that all object so you can differentiation that all objects and find all member of that object

Answer (score -1):

Just for the sake of inspiration. In Kotlin, you can create ad hoc objects:

```
val adHoc = object {
    var x = 1
    var y = 2
}
println(adHoc.x + adHoc.y)
```

Comment: This applies only to local and private scope