# Is it possible to make safe inline Optional in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, null, nullable, kotlin-inline-class

In Kotlin sometimes I have to work with double nullability. For example, I need double nullability, when I want to use `T?` where `T` may be a nullable type. There are a few approaches for doing this:

1. `Holder<T>?` where `Holder` is `data class Holder<out T>(val element: T)` - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001124/what-is-the-most-concise-way-to-include-functions-or-lambdas-as-conditions-in-a/58191904#58191904)<sup>1</sup>
2. `boolean` flag variable - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233684/update-field-when-others-fields-are-motifed/58236171#58236171)<sup>1</sup>
3. `containsKey` for `Map<K, T?>` - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213918/kotlin-how-to-create-dynamic-object/58219723#58219723)<sup>1</sup>
4. The special `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` for representing the second kind of `null` - [example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Lazy.kt)<sup>1</sup>

The last approach has the best performance, but it's also the most error-prone. So I've decided to encapsulate it in `inline class Optional<T>`:

```
inline class Optional<out T> @Deprecated(
    message = "Not type-safe, use factory method",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("Optional.of(_value)")
) constructor(private val _value: Any?) {
    val value: T?
        get() =
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            if (isPresent) _value as T
            else null

    val isPresent: Boolean
        get() = _value != NULL

    companion object {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        fun <T> of(value: T) = Optional<T>(value)

        fun <T : Any> ofNullable(value: T?): Optional<T> =
            if (value == null) EMPTY
            else of(value)

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        val EMPTY = Optional<Nothing>(NULL)
    }

    private object NULL
}

inline fun <T> Optional<T>.ifPresent(code: (T) -> Unit) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    if (isPresent) return code(value as T)
}

inline fun <T> Optional<T>.or(code: () -> T): T {
    ifPresent { return it }
    return code()
}
```

The first problem with this `Optional` is `public constructor`, which allows creating instances with arguments of not matching type.

The second problem was noticed at testing time. Here is the failed test:

```
emptyOr { Optional.EMPTY }.value assertEql null
```

```
fun <T> emptyOr(other: () -> T): T = Optional.EMPTY.or(other)
```

Exception:

```
Exception ClassCastException: Optional$NULL cannot be cast to Optional
    at (Optional.kt:42) // emptyOr { Optional.EMPTY }.value assertEql null
```

If I remove `inline` modifier from `Optional`, the test will pass.

**Q**: Is there any way to fix these problems without removing `inline` modifier from `Optional`?

---

<sup>1</sup> Examples include some context. Please read them fully before writing that I added incorrect links.

Comment: Why would you want double nullability in the first place?

Comment: @marstran check out examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001124/what-is-the-most-concise-way-to-include-functions-or-lambdas-as-conditions-in-a/58191904#58191904) (`Holder<R>?`), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233684/update-field-when-others-fields-are-motifed/58236171#58236171) (`boolean initialized`), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213918/kotlin-how-to-create-dynamic-object/58219723#58219723) (`containsKey`) and [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Lazy.kt) (`UNINITIALIZED_VALUE`)

Comment: Sure, but I would argue there are better ways to design those things than using nulls for everything. The last example with `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` is a good example. Using the internal object makes the intent much more clear. Using `containsKey` is also much clearer than first checking some holder for null, then checking the value for null.

Comment: Anyway, for your question, that exception seems to me like it is a bug with inline classes. You should report an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented exactly the same utility in one of my projects: [OptionalValue.kt](https://github.com/brutall/typedmap/blob/main/typedmap-core/src/main/kotlin/me/broot/typedmap/core/util/OptionalValue.kt). My implementation is very similar to yours, it is also an inline/value class, so it should be cpu/memory efficient and it passes all tests I throw at it.

Regarding your first question: about a public constructor. There is an annotation specifically for this case: [@PublishedApi](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-published-api/). I tried to reproduce ClassCastException from your example, but it worked for me without problems, so I believe it was a bug in Kotlin itself (?).

Also, to answer the question why do we need double nullability, I explained my point [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/proposal-for-the-option-maybe-datatype/469/27)