# Check if expression is null in Kotlin, Lua-style?

Tags: if-statement, kotlin, lua

In [Lua](https://www.lua.org/about.html) (which is rarely used outside of development in Corona SDK), you can evaluate ANY expression in an `if` statement as follows:

1. If expression is null, will return `false`
2. If expression is the boolean value `false`, will return `false`
3. Everything else will return `true`

Examples

```
if (1) // true
if ("Hello World") // true
if (instanceOfSomeRandomClass) // true
if ( [2, null, "foo"] ) // true
if (thisFunctionCallWithReturnNull()) // false
if (0 == 1) // false
```

`if` also happens to be an expression in Kotlin, so combining these features, I can see make creative ways to use it.

Is there an equivalent in Kotlin?

I know you can always manually check `if (expression != null)` and there's nothing wrong with that, but `if (expression)` is *lazier*, and I like being lazy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the [Kotlin language specification](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlin-spec/#conditional-expression):

> The type of the condition expression must be a subtype of kotlin.Boolean, otherwise it is an error.

So no, there is no direct equivalent in Kotlin.

However, you could potentially emulate the behaviour using a custom [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) on `Any?`:

```
fun Any?.toBoolean() = this != null && this != false
```

See it in action (note the `input.toBoolean()`):

```
fun main() {
    evaluate(1)
    evaluate("Hello World")
    evaluate(String())
    evaluate(listOf(2, null, "foo"))
    evaluate(null)
    evaluate(0 == 1)
}

fun evaluate(input: Any?) {
    println("$input is ${input.toBoolean()}")
}
```

Output:

```
1 is true
Hello World is true
 is true
[2, null, foo] is true
null is false
false is false
```

Not sure if this would qualify as "lazier", though.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more convenient, you can create a higher-order `luaIf` function:

```
sealed class LuaIf<T> {
    class True<T>(val value: T) : LuaIf<T>()
    object False : LuaIf<Nothing>()
}

inline fun <T> luaIf(condition: Any?, block: () -> T): LuaIf<T> =
    if (condition == null || condition == false) False as LuaIf<T>
    else True(block())

inline infix fun <T : R, R> LuaIf<T>.els(ifFalse: () -> R): R = when (this) {
    is True -> value
    False -> ifFalse()
}
```

And use it like this:

```
luaIf(null) { 1 } els { 0.5 } // 0.5
luaIf(Any()) { 1 } els { 0.5 } // 1
```

---

Unfortunately, every time the condition is `true` (or not `null`), the `LuaIf.True` instance is created. You can optimize it by inlining `LuaIf` class:

```
inline class LuaIf<T> @Deprecated(
    message = "Not type-safe, use factory method",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("luaIf(true) { _value }", "package.file.luaIf")
) constructor(val _value: Any?)

object LuaIfFalse

inline fun <T> luaIf(condition: Any?, ifTrue: () -> T): LuaIf<T> =
    if (condition == null || condition == false) LuaIf(LuaIfFalse)
    else LuaIf(ifTrue())

inline infix fun <T : R, R> LuaIf<T>.els(ifFalse: () -> R): R =
    if (_value == LuaIfFalse) ifFalse()
    else _value as T
```

Now, if you look at the bytecode of `println(luaIf(nullableAny) { 1 } els { 0.5 })`, you will see that no additional objects are created. Here is bytecode decompiled by me:

```
Object $this$els$iv = LuaIf.constructor-impl(
        nullableAny != null && !Intrinsics.areEqual(nullableAny, false) ? 1 : LuaIfFalse.INSTANCE
);
System.out.println(
        Intrinsics.areEqual($this$els$iv, LuaIfFalse.INSTANCE) ? 0.5 : $this$els$iv
);
```

```
public final class LuaIf {
   public static Object constructor-impl(@Nullable Object _value) {
      return _value;
   }
}
```

But since inline classes are experimental, they may lead to some bugs if you use them in a weird way. For example, the following code throws `ClassCastException: Integer cannot be cast to LuaIf`:

```
falseLua { luaIf(0) { 0 } } els { 0 }

fun <T> falseLua(other: () -> T): T = luaIf(false) { error("Impossible") } els other
```

I have already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256697/is-it-possible-to-make-safe-inline-optional-in-kotlin) about this exception.